# Cakephp plugin filter rename select

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.1

I have a plugin filter installed from https://github.com/lecterror/cakephp-filter-plugin.

How can i rename the values in the dropdown bar?

Right now I can choose between:

```
[ ]
[0]
[1]
```

What I need is:

```
[ ]
[Agent]
[Investor]
```

.

```
public $filters = array(
    'index' => array(
        'Model' => array( 
            'Model.Tablename' => array('label' => 'Find'),
            'Model.Tablename' => array(
                'label' => 'Position type',
                'type' => 'select',
                'selectOptions' => array (
                    0 => 'Agent',
                    1 => 'Investor'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

At the selector type I want to rename 0 to Agent and 1 to Investor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find it myself:

//plugincode-----> filter_form_fields

```
  foreach ($viewFilterParams as $field) {
        // Edited on  28-03-2013 
        // check if option type is select.
        if ($field['options']['type'] == "select") {
            // check for all option values ( 0,1,2,3,4 ect ) and rename it with optionNewValue
            foreach ($field['options']['options'] as $optionvalue) {
                $optionNewValue = $field['options']['OptionKey'][$optionvalue];
                // Rename the optionvalue
                $field['options']['options'][$optionvalue] = $optionNewValue;
            }
        }
```

// filtercomponent.ctp add (plugin code )

> // Optionkey gives the values filter_form_fields
>                           // use inside the controller Optionkey => array()  to rename values 
>                           $options['OptionKey'] = $settings['OptionKey'];

and now you can put in the controller

```
'index' => array(
        'Model' => array( 
            'Model.Tablename' => array('label' => 'Find'),
            'Model.Tablename' => array(
                'label' => 'Position type',
                 'type' => 'select',
                'OptionKey' => array (
                    0 => 'agent',
                    1 => 'investor'

            )
        )
    )
);
```

:D:D:D:D:D